# Reduce wxWidgets size Mac and disable PNG

Tags: macos, static, wxwidgets, strip

I edited the port file to create wxWidgets statically because I wanted to reduce the executable size. At first I used dynamic linking and dylibbundler, but that resulted in ~40 MB size for the Bundle. Using statically linked wxWidgets and a bunch of strip settings, I can get the executable to ~10 MB and the bundle to 11 MB. However, I know for a fact that the simple program is still using libpng.a because when I remove the library in the link options, I get link errors. I tried specifying wxNO_PNG_LIB in the prefix header, before any includes, all over the place until Xcode started complaining about redefinitions. For such a simple application, I'd like to be able to have a smaller application size, and I think removing PNG and perhaps some other strip commands is all that I have left.

However, if anyone knows better ways to reduce wxWidgets size, I'm using macports GCC 4.9 with Xcode and statically compiled wxwidgets30 from port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining `wxNO_PNG_LIB` won't help under Mac, it's MSVC-specific. You need to build your own version of wxWidgets without PNG support (although this is really the last thing I'd want to disable) and everything else you can get away with. Basically start by running `configure --disable-all-features` and then add enable options for everything you do need.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I can add my own variant to the wxwidgets30 port file which is a barebones version. That's the great thing about macports, I can switch between the variants. Thanks for the suggestion.